# How to show the JFrame with correct tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have created 2 Jtabbedpane. 
First Tab contains one menu. if i click the menu Jframe is opened. 
if I click on second second tab, the Jframe will minimized and if I go for first tab, the opened Jframe should appears on the tab.